# Replace the list items with specific characters using lambda

Tags: c#

[image]

This will give me the list of string having "WIGS_AUTH_" in each item. Now I want to remove this part from the list items in the same expression. Or any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Please have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please see [ask]

Comment: Also, don't post images of code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code sample is an image, which isn't permitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add another `Select` at the end

```
List<PermissionDto> ans = result
                         .Where(x => x.Contains("WIGS_AUTH_"))
                         .Select(x => new PermissionDto { Name = x.Replace("WIGS_AUTH_", "") })
                         .ToList();
```

Comment: try the updated expression, I tried it and it's working with me

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:
result.Where(x => x.Contains("WIGS_AUTH")).Select(x => new Permision() { Name=x.Replace("WIGS_AUTH","") }).ToList();

1. First its filtering the result and taking items containing "WING_AUT"
2. now it is creating  new object of PermissionDto and set name property without "WIGS_AUTH"
3. adding new object to list and returning back